# Programmatically create textview background from drawable in Android

Tags: android, background, gradient, textview

I have to set the background programmatically on Android TextView

I have using below code. it's not working and also its gave me nullpointerexception error.

```
best_deals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bestdeals);
 best_deals.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(
                                       R.drawable.headerradius));
```

but I have to put these

`best_deals.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#be2351"));` means it's working

what's wrong in above code?

This is my **header_redius.xml**:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
     <corners 
      android:radius="15dp"
     />
     <gradient
            android:startColor="#434343"
             android:centerColor="#434343"
            android:endColor="#434343"
            android:angle="270" 
            android:type="linear"
            />
        <padding android:left="10dp"
     android:top="0dp"
     android:right="10dp"
     android:bottom="0dp"/> 
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#000000" />
            </shape>
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to use `setBackgroundResource()` method.

For example :

```
best_deals.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.headerradius);
```

More about [setBackgroundResource().](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks for give me such a good solution...i have tried already these solution.but my id is wrong.that's why am getting nullpointer error exception.now am getting the output.thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**The Final code that worked**

The older API than JELLYBEAN have different way to load drawable programatically. Try this:

```
       final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            textView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_rect_outline));
        } else {
            textView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_rect_outline));
        }
```